# Automate import of CSV files in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I'm currently using SSIS to import a whole slew of CSV files into our system on a regular basis. These import processes are scheduled using the SQL Server Agent - which should have a happy ending. However, one of our vendors from which we're receiving data likes to change up the file format every now and then (feels like twice a month) and it is a royal pain to implement these changes in SSIS.

Is there a less painful way for me to get these imported into SQL Server?  My requirements are fairly simple:

1. The file formats are CSV, they're delimited with commas, and are text qualified with double quotes.
2. The file name will indicate into which table I need these imported
3. It needs to be something which can be automated
4. Changes in file format should not be that much of a pain
5. If something does go wrong, I need to be able to know what it was - logging of some sort

Thanks so much!

Comment: Based on I know, you have to `Reset the columns` and map the columns again for new format file, SSIS could be automated, but not that smart to auto detect I guess

Comment: how are the file formats changing? Like csv to txt to xls? If that's the case, I'd use a batch job to just standardize the type and file name before the ssis package runs

Comment: @LONG Yep, that's the issue here.

Comment: @scsimon as in adding fields. I'd get this weird nonsensical error, which I later learned means that it cannot find the line terminator where it was expecting it. That's when I need to be busy with data types, size. test, deploy

Answer (score 1):

`BULK INSERT` is another option you can choose. You can define your own templets of the file with it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql

https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/using-sql-bulk-insert-with-a-format-file/

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using BIML, which dynamically generates packages based on the meta data at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Java solution "dbis". Please check below.

https://dbisweb.wordpress.com/

It have migration info in to xml file. You can edit it in any text editor.
But it will need static table name.